# Why is target not defined

Tags: python, discord.py

I am coding a discord economy bot with discord.py, but my share command doesn't work:

```
if message.content.startswith('bott share'):
        try:
            target, amount = message.content.split(' ')[1:]
            amount = int(amount)
        except ValueError:
            await message.channel.send('Invalid Arguments')
        target = target[2:-1]
        if target[0] == '!':
            target = target[1:]
        target = int(target)
        if amount > getcoins(user):
            await message.channel.send('ARE YOU TRYING TO HJACK THE SYSTEM?')
        elif amount < 0:
            await message.channel.send('ARE YOU TRYING TO HJACK THE SYSTEM?')
        setcoins(user, getcoins(user)-amount)
        setcoins(target, getcoins(target)+amount)
        await message.channel.send(f'You gave {target} {amount}, and now you have {getcoins(user)}.')
```

When I run it it said:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord
/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)  File "main.py", line 601, in on_message
    target = target[2:-1]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'target' referenced before as
signment
```

Comment: I'd try printing the target, to see if it contains what you think it does.

Comment: @Chris It didn't work, but thanks

Comment: that should be your first indicator that something is wrong

Comment: If the first line of that `try` block fails, then no value gets assigned to `target` (or `amount`).  You either need to: A) pre-assign values to these variables, B) assign something to them in the `except` clause, or C) have the `except` clause completely exit the function so that you don't try to proceed without these variables having a value.

Comment: `target, amount = message.content.split(' ')[1:]` works if and only if `message.content.split(' ')[1:]` has a length of 2, which it probably doesn't. If/when it fails, you `target` does not get assigned.

Comment: when you run `target, amount = ...` and there will be error then it will not create variables `target, amount` but after error you try to use `target[2:-1]` - so you try to get from variable which may not exists. You should skip all code when you get error.

Comment: Ok, guys, I fixed the problem. It was supposed to be

   ```target, amount = message.content.split(' ')[2:]```

not 

    ```target, amount = message.content.split(' ')[1:]```

because it is the second spit, not the first. Thanks for helping tho

Answer (score 1):

When you run

```
 target, amount = message.content.split(' ')[1:]
```

and there will be error then it will not create variables `target`, `amount` but after catching this error you run `target[2:-1]` and then it tries to get value from not existing variable

You could put all inside try/except

```
if message.content.startswith('bott share'):
    try:
        target, amount = message.content.split(' ')[1:]
        amount = int(amount)
            target = target[2:-1]
        if target[0] == '!':
            target = target[1:]
        target = int(target)
        if amount > getcoins(user):
            await message.channel.send('ARE YOU TRYING TO HJACK THE SYSTEM?')
        elif amount < 0:
            await message.channel.send('ARE YOU TRYING TO HJACK THE SYSTEM?')
        setcoins(user, getcoins(user)-amount)
        setcoins(target, getcoins(target)+amount)
        await message.channel.send(f'You gave {target} {amount}, and now you have {getcoins(user)}.')
    except ValueError:
        await message.channel.send('Invalid Arguments')
```

or you could set some default value before `try/except` or inside `except`

```
    target = None
    amount = None

    try:
        target, amount = message.content.split(' ')[1:]
        amount = int(amount)
    except ValueError:
        await message.channel.send('Invalid Arguments')

    if target is not None and amount is not None:
       target = target[2:-1]
       # ... rest ...
```

or eventually - but if `target` is empty string or `amount` is `0` then `if` will give `False`

```
    if target and amount:
       target = target[2:-1]
       # ... rest ...
```

If you run this code in function then you could use `return` to finish function

```
    try:
        target, amount = message.content.split(' ')[1:]
        amount = int(amount)
    except ValueError:
        await message.channel.send('Invalid Arguments')
        return  # finish function
```